# Using sass modules with Typescript in Next JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, next.js

I'm trying to edit the default Webpack config in Next JS so my sass files are able to work with CSS modules, whilst also having the compilation process output my declaration files for my sass to be used with Typescript.

I've seen many examples of this working with normal css, but can't get it to work with Typescript.

Here's the current setup of my next.config.js :

```
module.exports = withCustomBabelConfigFile(
  withTypeScript(withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    babelConfigFile: path.resolve("./babel.config.js"),
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push(
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            "style-loader",
            {
              loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
              options: {modules: true,nameExport: true,camelCase: true,sass: true}
            },
            "sass-loader"
          ]

        }
      );
      return config
    }
  }))
);
```

The `typings-for-css-modules-loader` I believe is key for achieving the TS declaration file output, but I keep getting the following errors:

`./pages/home/index.scss
$font-size: 50px;
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in /Users/sites/project/pages/home/index.scss (line 1, column 1)`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is you have try new  installing @zeit/next-sass module as [ this article](https://medium.com/quick-code/next-js-style-with-sass-scss-fonts-54e9cef70377)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydDUm1yPZs0&lc=UgybSfrM0NdkNRwJaAt4AaABAg.9Hdzf8Xhu6c9HlM4nMxHFq - Maybe this video - plus my comment using sass + sass-loader are likely to help you here